# Double brace initialization java. Куда указывает this?

Tags: java, рефлексия, инициализация, this

Пишу свой data класс, чтобы потом все поля конвертировать в Map. Условно имею что-то похожее:

```
public class Variables {
    private EEO eeo;

    public EEO getEeo() {
        if (eeo == null) eeo = new EEO();
        return eeo;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        var map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        for (Field declaredVariable : this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (declaredVariable != null) {
                Map<String, Object> declaredEntries = new HashMap<>();
                for (Field declaredField : declaredVariable.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                    Object field = null;
                    try {
                        field = declaredField.get(eeo);
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (field instanceof AbstractMap.SimpleEntry) {
                        AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Object> entry = (AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Object>) field;
                        declaredEntries.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                    }
                }
                map.put(declaredVariable.getClass().getSimpleName(), declaredEntries);
            }

        }
        return map;
    }

    public class EEO {
        public AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String> target;

        public AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String> getTarget() {
            if (target == null) target = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("target", null);
            return target;
        }
    }
}
```

Помимо класса EEO будут еще подобные. Решил использовать рефлексию, дабы можно было расширить в дальнейшем.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой - если инициализировать данный класс через double brace, то this в методе toMap() будет указывать не на данный объект Varibles, а на объект класса Test где была произведена инициализация такого класса:

```
public class Test {
public void test() {
        var variables = new Variables() {{
            getEeo().getTarget().setValue("trgt");
            getEeo().getSource().setValue("src");
        }}.toMap();
}
}
```

Соответвственно вся рефлексия валится, так как читает поля не с того объекта.

В случае с обычной инициализацией через `new Variables();` и дальнейшим построчным setEeo() и тд все работает правильно, this указывает на инстанс Variables.

```
var variables = new Variables();
        variables.getEeo().getTarget().setValue("trgt");
        variables.getEeo().getSource().setValue("src");
        variables.toMap();
```

Почему это так работает? И есть ли какое-то решение, помимо приведенного в конце?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы неправильно интерпретируете то, что происходит.

`this` в `toMap` в этом примере не указывает на объект `Test` и `getClass` не возвращает класс `Test`. Дело в том, что вы создаете анонимный внутренний класс, когда используете эту конструкцию:

```
new Variables() {
   ...
}
```

и именно его вы видите. Класс анонимный в том смысле, что вы ему имя не дали и обращаться по имени не можете. Компилятор сгенерировал для него имя типа `Test$1` и скорее всего его вы приняли за класс `Test`. Но это отдельный класс унаследованный от `Variables`.

Есть альтернативный вариант сделать то, что вы хотите без использвования анонимного внутреннего класса - это использовать лямбду с обратным вызовом для инициализации. По краткости практически то же самое. Вот демонстрация подхода (и ваш подход для сравнения):

```
class Variables {
    
    public Variables() {}
    
    public Variables(java.util.function.Consumer<Variables> initializer) {
        initializer.accept(this);
    }
    
    public void getEeo() {
        System.out.println("in getEeo()");
    }
    
    public Variables toMap() {
        System.out.println("in toMap(): " + this);
        return this;
    }
}

public class MyClass {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Variables v1 = new Variables() {{
            getEeo();
        }}.toMap();
        
        Variables v2 = new Variables(vars -> {
            vars.getEeo();
        }).toMap();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Ага, посмотрел повнимательней и правда выглядит как внутренний класс. Спасибо, решил ваш подход использовать.